# what are the steps to compile and run NVIDIA PhysX (version4) Kapla Demo and sample code using cmake?

Tags: cmake, physx

I am trying to get into NVIDIA PhysX SDK. But cannot find how to actually run the following,

Kapla Demo:

https://github.com/NVIDIAGameWorks/PhysX/tree/4.1/kaplademo

Other Samples:

https://github.com/NVIDIAGameWorks/PhysX/tree/4.1/physx/samples
.

i followed the instructions here,

http://gameworksdocs.nvidia.com/PhysX/4.1/documentation/physxguide/Manual/BuildingWithPhysX.html

to get a build with

```
    sudo ./generate_projects linux
```

and ended up with a document hierarchy that i cannot make heads or tails of.

it would be great if i can link the Kapla Demo and other Examples with a single CMake script. All help is much much appreciated.!